# CardView bottom border is cut off inside ScrollView android

Tags: android, scrollview, cardview

I am putting the cardview inside scrollview, we expect to see that at the bottom, the border should be shown（see pic below）. But its not. The problem is that I cannot scroll to the bottom to see the border of cardview.

All the solutions on SO is to change layout_margins to paddings, but its not the case for cardview if we want to show the border. I basically tried everything. But still doesnt work.
[image: scroll to bottom cannot see the border]

Picture 1. scroll to bottom cannot see the border

[image: we can see the top border]

Picture 2. We can see the top border

Following is xml code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      >
                     ...
                    </LinearLayout>
           </CardView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

references: 
[ScrollView doesn't scroll to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131962/scrollview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-bottom?rq=1)

[ScrollView cuts off the top and leaves space at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922866/scrollview-cuts-off-the-top-and-leaves-space-at-the-bottom)

[I can't show LinearLayout at bottom to scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937681/i-cant-show-linearlayout-at-bottom-to-scroll-view)

[Android ScrollView refuses to scroll to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660937/android-scrollview-refuses-to-scroll-to-bottom)

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to help us better understand what is going on?

Comment: @Vucko screen shot added, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution I just found is to wrap CardView with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and set its padding. For example, If you want some drop shadow effect in cardView, lets say 8dp, you can set 4dp padding of your LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and 4dp layout_margin of CardView.

Comment: yeah, but adding an extra layer will take the extra time to traverse the view tree, which is not optimized. Well, if you're not care about the performance, that should work

Comment: I did not even had to set the padding. Just added the linear layout and it solved the problem

Answer (score 35):

**UPDATED**

This will work better now with a `NestedScrollView` and a `MaterialCardView`. I added this `NestedScrollView` to a `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

This is working for me without the LinearLayout wrapper.

===========================================================================

**OLD WAY LEFT HERE**

I ran into the same problem and had to do the following (the key is the LinearLayout wrapper around the cardview where I added the **paddingBottom**):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/item_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_wrapper_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/content_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/item_cardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Adding the **LinearLayout wrapper** around the cardview is what worked for me.

Also note, I had to add **card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"** on the cardview to get the border shadow looking correct.

Here is the end result where the red box shows where the padding has been added when the cardview is expanded and scrolled up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not a big fan of adding an extra layer to wrap the cardview, it will take extra time to traverse the view tree, especially true when view is deep. If you are not care about the performance, that should work

Comment: Adding a LinearLayout as a wrapper is not going to cause a huge performance increase on this design. If this was all contained in a RecyclerView, then I could see that it might be an issue. A view like this should not be that deep anyways - esp above the card.

Comment: There is apparently a margin or padding issue if you see the screen shot above. The scrollbar can not be scrolled anymore even if it reached to the bottom. So fixing this padding/margin issue is the right way to do. Wrapping a linearlayout just a hack way, or IMHO, it works by coincidence.

Comment: I couldn't make this work and the only thing that worked was adding `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` in `CardView` as explained in this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Setting `clipToPadding` to `false` on a `ScrollView` usually works for me:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:contentPadding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum..." />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: just adding `clipToPadding` to `false` to the parent of the MaterialCardView worked for me

Comment: This requires `clipToPadding="false"` and `paddingBottom`. If just the `clipToPadding` is added, it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just have to change `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` to solve the problem.

FYI, my `NestedScrollView` is placed inside a fragment which is a child of `CoordinatorLayout` with `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` set.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is adding View with marginTop at last

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"> 

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


      ...................
      ...................

       <View
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0.1dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Moving margin from child to `ScrollView` worked for me

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      >
                     ...
                    </LinearLayout>
           </CardView>
  </LinearLayout>
```